# C++ Random ID, and random Answers

Tags: c++, char

Im making a program that outputs an ID, and the random guesses of the answers.
You can guess A, B, C, D, and the ID has random characters in the first 2 letters, and numbers in the next 3.

> The error is that the program gives me an ID like this: YN420BBBBCBACDBBCDB

You can see the ID clearly in it. But, it puts the random answer with it, and its in one variable. Here's my code:

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <ctime>
        #include <cstdlib>
        #include <string>
        #include <fstream>

        using namespace std;

        char id[6];
        char answers[16];

        int main()
        {
            srand(time(NULL));
            int random =rand() % 500+1;
            const char* const a_to_d       = "ABCD"                       ;
            const char* const a_to_z       = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" ;
            const char* const zero_to_seven = "01234567";

            for (int i = 0; i < random; ++i){
            int ri = rand()  % 26;
            id[0] = a_to_z[ri];
            int ri1 = rand() % 26;
            id[1] = a_to_z[ri1];

            int ri2 = rand() % 7;
            id[2] = zero_to_seven[ri2];
            int ri3 = rand() % 7;
            id[3] = zero_to_seven[ri3];
            int ri4 = rand() % 7;
            id[4] = zero_to_seven[ri4];
            id[6] = 0;
            cout<<id<<"     "<<answers<<endl<<endl;

            int fi   = rand() % 4;
            answers[0]  = a_to_d[fi];
            int fi1  = rand() % 4;
            answers[1]  = a_to_d[fi1];
            int fi2  = rand() % 4;
            answers[2]  = a_to_d[fi2];
            int fi3  = rand() % 4;
            answers[3]  = a_to_d[fi3];
            int fi4  = rand() % 4;
            answers[4]  = a_to_d[fi4];
            int fi5  = rand()  % 4;
            answers[5]  = a_to_d[fi5];
            int fi6  = rand() % 4;
            answers[6]  = a_to_d[fi6];
            int fi7  = rand() % 4;
            answers[7]  = a_to_d[fi7];
            int fi8  = rand() % 4;
            answers[8]  = a_to_d[fi8];
            int fi9  = rand() % 4;
            answers[9]  = a_to_d[fi9];
            int fi10 = rand() % 4;
            answers[10] = a_to_d[fi10];
            int fi11 = rand() % 4;
            answers[11] = a_to_d[fi11];
            int fi12 = rand() % 4;
            answers[12] = a_to_d[fi12];
            int fi13 = rand() % 4;
            answers[13] = a_to_d[fi13];
            int fi14 = rand() % 4;
            answers[14] = a_to_d[fi14];
            answers[16] = 0;
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: `random.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
random.cpp:33:9: warning: array subscript 4 is above array bounds of ‘char [4]’ [-Warray-bounds]
     id[4] = zero_to_seven[ri4];
     ~~~~^
random.cpp:65:15: warning: array subscript 14 is above array bounds of ‘char [14]’ [-Warray-bounds]
     answers[14] = a_to_d[fi14];
     ~~~~~~~~~~^
`

Comment: You need to enable more warnings when compiling.

Comment: It compiles for me tho.

Comment: Me too, but it gives me the warnings (which are really bad) and also runtime errors.

`random.cpp:33:9: runtime error: index 4 out of bounds for type 'char [4]'
random.cpp:33:11: runtime error: store to address 0x00000060596a with insufficient space for an object of type 'char'
0x00000060596a: note: pointer points here
 44 4a  30 31 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00`
...

Comment: Never really saw anything like this before, im kinda new. Can you explain that one for me, please?

Comment: Also, there are 26 letters in the alphabet, not 25.

Comment: `id[4] = ...` - that's just plain wrong. Your `id` array is only of size 4, so valid indices are 0, 1, 2, 3. The index 4 is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your char array needs to be null-terminated. Since its not, cout continues into the next array, until finally it finds a null-terminator. To fix this, simply increase the length by one `char id[5]` and set the last value to 0 `id[4] = 0`

Also, your modulus operators will never cover the last value for ri and ri2. `rand() % 25` the largest value you can get is 24. You actually want `rand() % 26`.

Comment: But you have `id[4] = zero_to_seven[ri4];` and `answers[14] = a_to_d[fi14];`. I think you need to make them `char id[6]` and `char answer[16]`. and set id[5] and answer[15] to '\0'.